# reset dropdown list to original after it is load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<select id="ddl" name="ddl">
  <option value="Col">loading</option>
</select>
<select id="ddlCol" name="ddlCol">
  <option value="Col">loading</option>
</select>
<select id="ddlCol2" name="ddlCol">
  <option value="Col">loading</option>
</select>
$("#ddl").change(function(){
  $("#ddlcol").load(Test1.html);
});
$("#ddlcol").change(function(){
  $("#ddlcol2").load(Test2.html);
});
```

Now i have 3 dropdown lists.
when my first dropdown list select `dll` field. `ddlCol` will be load with `test1.html`
after my `ddlCol` select a value `ddlcol2` will load with `test2.html`

What i want know is if i select first dropdown list how to reset `ddlcol2` to its default value?
example

> ddl
>
> Apple
>
> Orange
>
> Pear
>
> ddlCol
>
> $1
>
> $2
>
> $3
>
> ddlCol2
>
> Red
>
> Green
>
> Purple
>
> Select Apple.
>
> ddlCol change
>
> $1
>
> $1.50
>
> $2
>
> Select $1
>
> ddlCol2 change
>
> Blue
>
> Pink
>
> Now Select Pear
>
> my ddlCol2 will reset back to
>
> Red
>
> Green
>
> Purple

.
how am i going to reset it?

Comment: I think your question and the code you provided don't make sense together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var refreshColThenCol2 = function(){
   $("#ddlCol1").html($("#ddl2").html());
};
```

i think loading t this way is much better

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger them accordingly when they need to be reloaded.

```
var refreshColThenCol2 = function(){
  $("#ddlcol").load(url, refreshCol2);
};

var refreshCol2 = function(){ 
  $("#ddlcol2").load(url);
};

$("#ddl").change(refreshColThenCol2);
$("#ddlcol").change(refreshCol2);
```

Comment: if i have 10 ddl. 1->2->3->4 each affect sequencing for each ddl. now i choose first ddl change. 3 4..N will retain the value. which is not what i want. i want 3 4..N being reset to its default value in ddl.

Comment: @user1397840, it is the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Simple and effective function and works for me. \ Insert this in between some script tags on the page you wish to have it work on.

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("IDofyourdropdown").selectedIndex = 0;
}
```